# Typescript return and async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am facing a design problem in typescript. In my controller I do a validation and validation method returns 422 response which ends the thread or a validated data which I am trying to use. So here is my code. In my controller I have

```
async createFeed(ctx : HttpContextContract){
    await this.feedValidator.createFeedValidate(ctx)
    return this.feedService.createFeed(ctx)
  }
```

Here `await this.feedValidator.createFeedValidate(ctx)` does the validation logic and this method return 422 or a validated object

```
try {
        const payload = await ctx.request.validate({ schema: createFeedSchema, messages : msg })
        return payload
      } catch (error) {
         return ctx.response.status(422).send(error.messages)
  }
```

Right now, with this approach, I am not being able to access the `payload`  returned by the validation method.

If I try

```
let validatedData = await this.feedValidator.createFeedValidate(ctx)
return this.feedService.createFeed(ctx,validatedData)
```

Then the thread doesn't stop if validation returns `return ctx.response.status(422).send(error.messages)`

Is there anyways, I can do method chaining or have nice advanced solution?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Simply do not send the 422 response inside the `createFeedValidate` method. All it should do is throw a validation error. The endpoint (controller?) should be responsible for converting that into the respective http error and sending the response - also it should write the feed into the response in the success case. Do not pass that `ctx` all around.

Comment: So you mean I need to add logic in the controller and then construct the response? And thank you for ctx tips

Comment: Yes. Although I'm unsure why your http controller does `return` something. Each of your methods should either `return`/`throw`, or write to the http response (and not return anything and never throw). But I don't know what framework you are using (if any) so I don't know the exact conventions you should use.

Comment: Controller return to front end. It returns error or success data coming from service class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using AdonisJS.
If you look at the documentation, the send method ( `ctx.response.status(422).send(error.messages)`) returns 'void', i.e. nothing.
That's why you can't get the return from your try catch.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

Your createFeedValidateMethod should only contains this :

```
return ctx.request.validate({ schema: createFeedSchema, messages : msg })
```

and in your controller :

```
async createFeed(ctx : HttpContextContract){
   try {
    let validatedData = await this.feedValidator.createFeedValidate(ctx)
    return this.feedService.createFeed(ctx, validatedData)
   } catch (err) {
     return ctx.response.status(422).send(error.messages)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much better, I missed this. Thanks again